# Numbering Last Equation in List of Equations

Tags: equations, numbering

I am using the following code to create a list of equations,

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{rcll}
  \| \hat{\textbf{v}}_{i}^{*} \|^{2} & = & \left\| \hat{\textbf{v}}_{i}^{*} + \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} \mu_{i,j}\hat{\textbf{v}}_{j}^{*} \right\|^{2} & \mbox{from (\ref{eqn:gram-schmit-orthogonalization})}, \notag \\
    & = & \| \hat{\textbf{v}}_{i}^{*} \|^{2} + \sum_{j = 1}^{i-1} \mu_{i,j}^{2} \| \hat{\textbf{v}}_{j}^{*} \|^{2} & \mbox{since~} \hat{\textbf{v}}_{1}^{*}, \ldots, \hat{\textbf{v}}_{n}^{*} \mbox{~are orthogonal}, \notag \\
    & \leq & \| \hat{\textbf{v}}_{i}^{*} \|^{2} + \sum_{j = 1}^{i-1} \frac{1}{4} \| \hat{\textbf{v}}_{j}^{*} \|^{2} & \mbox{since~} | \mu_{i,j} | \leq \frac{1}{2}, \notag \\
    & = & \| \hat{\textbf{v}}_{i}^{*} \|^{2} + \sum_{j = 1}^{i-1} 2^{i-j-2} \| \hat{\textbf{v}}_{i}^{*} \|^{2} & \mbox{from (\ref{eqn:lovasz-useful-estimate})}, \notag \\
    & = & \frac{1+2^{i-1}}{2} \| \hat{\textbf{v}}_{i}^{*} \|^{2} & \notag \\
    & \leq & 2^{i-1} \| \hat{\textbf{v}}_{i}^{*} \|^{2} & \mbox{since~} 1 \leq 2^{i-1} \mbox{~for all~} i \geq 1. \label{eqn:lovasz-simplification} \\
  \end{array}
\end{equation}
```

What I want to do is put a label (or number) against the last equation in the list.  I am not quite sure how to do this.  I have tried searching online, and the closest that I have been able to find is using the `\tag{...}` command of the `align` environment.  Unfortunately, this environment only allows the equation to be split into two.   I want more control over splitting the equation, which is why I chose the `array` environment to split the equations into four segments.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you need more alignment points, simply use the `alignat` environment. For details refer to the [amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) user guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you wrote that you don't like `align`, but I believe that the following code does exactly what you want. Notice that I use `\text` and `\mathbf`, which is more proper than `\mbox` and `\textbf`. The `\text` command does better font handling and `\mathbf` should be used for upright bold math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \| \hat{\mathbf{v}}_{i}^{*} \|^{2} & = \left\| \hat{\mathbf{v}}_{i}^{*} + \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} \mu_{i,j}\hat{\mathbf{v}}_{j}^{*} \right\|^{2} && \text{from (\ref{eqn:gram-schmit-orthogonalization})}, \notag \\
    & = \| \hat{\mathbf{v}}_{i}^{*} \|^{2} + \sum_{j = 1}^{i-1} \mu_{i,j}^{2} \| \hat{\mathbf{v}}_{j}^{*} \|^{2} && \text{since~} \hat{\mathbf{v}}_{1}^{*}, \ldots, \hat{\mathbf{v}}_{n}^{*} \text{~are orthogonal}, \notag \\
    & \leq \| \hat{\mathbf{v}}_{i}^{*} \|^{2} + \sum_{j = 1}^{i-1} \frac{1}{4} \| \hat{\mathbf{v}}_{j}^{*} \|^{2} && \text{since~} | \mu_{i,j} | \leq \frac{1}{2}, \notag \\
    & = \| \hat{\mathbf{v}}_{i}^{*} \|^{2} + \sum_{j = 1}^{i-1} 2^{i-j-2} \| \hat{\mathbf{v}}_{i}^{*} \|^{2} && \text{from (\ref{eqn:lovasz-useful-estimate})}, \notag \\
    & = \frac{1+2^{i-1}}{2} \| \hat{\mathbf{v}}_{i}^{*} \|^{2} \notag \\
    & \leq 2^{i-1} \| \hat{\mathbf{v}}_{i}^{*} \|^{2} && \text{since~} 1 \leq 2^{i-1} \text{~for all~} i \geq 1. \label{eqn:lovasz-simplification}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for that!  I didn't realize that the `align` environment had a double ampersand (`&&`) option!

Comment: It has something like 20 columns, and the odd ones are formatted right, the even ones left and there is a "stretch" between each pair of `{rl}` columns. As well, **the columnsep is set in such way that you should use `&` in front of the relation/operator**, so `&=` is correct whereas `=&` is not.

Comment: @tohecz -- the "v"s in the expression, although bold, are still math.  better to use `\mathbf` instead of `\textbf`.  this does not apply to the use of `\text`, which should definitely be used when there is *real* text in the display.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sorry, I did not check the input precisely, which I should have. I simply used the code by Bill. I'm correcting it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Yep!  That's my fault!  Thanks for the advice Barbara!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `\notag` you can define `\eqnumtag` taht inserts the number in `{align*}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\eqnumtag}{%
   % step the counter and make it lable-able
   \refstepcounter{equation}%
   % print the counter as tag
   \tag{\theequation}%
}

\begin{document}
Reference to eq.~(\ref{eqn:test}) and (\ref{eqn:test2}).
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
Text
\begin{align*}
   a &= b \\
   0 &= 0 \\
   1 &= 1 \eqnumtag\label{eqn:test}
\end{align*}
Text
\begin{equation}
2^2=4
\end{equation}
Text
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align*}
   a &= b \\
   0 &= 0 \\
   1 &= 1 \eqnumtag\label{eqn:test2}
\end{align*}
Text
\begin{equation}
2^2=4
\end{equation}
Text
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image: eqtag]

Note that this solution also works with `{subequations}`.

Comment: Thanks Tobi, but I rather like tohecz's solution as it more closely resembles what I am used to using the `array` environment.