# Unable to number equations when using commands \begin{equation} \begin{split}

Tags: numbering

I am attempting to split three equations onto separate lines, and I wish to number my last equation, I am starting my commands with `\begin{equation} \begin{split}`, and after the first and second equation I am using the command `\nonumber`, however my last equation is not being numbered either. When I do not use the `\nonumber` command, only my second equation is being numbered. I am not too sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The combination `equation` and `split` will give you just one number for the whole group of equations, you want `align` with `\nonumber`/`\notag`, e.g. [Numbering Last Equation in List of Equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46344)

Comment: With an `equation` environment, you get only one, vertically centered equation number, no matter how many lines the `split` environment contains.

Comment: That's great, I didn't realise that I couldn't use both equation and split together. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can use them together, but you get one number for the whole display (which logically might be better than having all but one line unnumbered and just numbering one line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an `equation` environment, you get only one, vertically centered equation number, no matter how many lines the `split` environment contains. Your `\nonumber` statements actually have no effect.

You should, instead, use an `align` environment, along the following lines:

```
\begin{align}
a &= b \nonumber \\
  &= c \nonumber \\
  &= d 
\end{align}
```

That way, only the final row will get an equation number attached to it.